# Position absolute of div inside scrollable div doesn't work properly

Tags: css

I have a box which displays the contents of a chosen file using jquery.
The code for the box is

```
<div class="lightbox">
<div class="lightbox-content"></div>
<div id="close-lightbox">Close</div>
</div>
```

I want the close-lightbox div to be always at the bottom of the box.So the css for it is

```
#close-lightbox{color:red;position:absolute;bottom:0;padding-left:30%;}
```

Div `lightbox` has `overflow:auto`.
Now, what happens is that if the `lightbox-content` is not big and it fits the fixed size of `lightbox` then there is no scrolling and the `close-ligthbox` does appear at the bottom as I wanted.
But if the `lightbox-content` is big and doesn't fit the fixed size of lightbox then there is scrolling but the `close-lightbox` appears at the bottom of the lightbox BEFORE that scrolls down which means it appears on the middle of the `lightbox-content`.

Any suggestions how I can fix that?

Comment: any example you can show us? Either on a jsFiddle or the site itself?

Comment: Have you tried to set `.lightbox{position:relative;}` ? That way the `close-lightbox` div will be relative to the main container and it will always be at the bottom (with the css you've posted)

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/takis/2CtTh/ .  The Close doesn't appear at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap lightbox in its own wrapper, and position the close-lightbox relative to it.

HTML

```
<div class="lightbox-wrapper">
    <div class="lightbox">
        <div class="lightbox-content"></div>
        <div id="close-lightbox">Close</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.lightbox-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#close-lightbox {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 30%;
}
```

Take a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/4chu6/

**EDIT** Ohgodwhy's solution is actually cleaner if you're able to move lightbox's `overflow:auto` to lightbox-content -> While I was at it, I made fiddle with his solution - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/4chu6/2/

Comment: This way Close-lightbox always appear. I want that to appear after close-lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
.lightbox{
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.lightbox-content{
  height:270px;
  overflow:auto;  
}
```

Change the height of this based on your needs of your lightbox.

Comment: I tried that but then there is no scrolling if the text is big

Comment: @Takis what? I would need to see an example, this makes no sense.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/takis/2CtTh/ . The Close-lightbox doesn't appear on the end

Comment: @Takis The fiddle you linked to me is nothing near what I suggested. [This. This is what I was suggesting.](http://jsfiddle.net/2CtTh/1/)

Comment: The fiddle was my code to show you what the problem was. In your example the Close-lightbox does not appear after the lightbox-content.It appears ALWAYS outside. I want it to appear at the end as if it is part of the contnent